# How to get local time from a specific string adding hh:mm

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format, gmt

I have this date in this format:

```
String date = "2018-12-08T07:50:00+01:00";
```

And I'd like to get the local time in this format (adding the hours over GMT) but I'm not able to do it

```
date = "2018-12-08 08:50:00";
```

Other example:

```
String date = "2018-12-08T07:50:00+04:00";
```

Result:

```
date = "2018-12-08 11:50:00";
```

Any help?

Comment: Similar to [Convert OffsetDateTime to UTC Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651210/convert-offsetdatetime-to-utc-timestamp) (though likely not a strict duplicate). I think you should be able to piece the answer together from what your search engine can bring you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sun already said in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916688/5772882), you misunderstood: `2018-12-08T07:50:00+01:00` is the same point in time as `2018-12-08 06:50:00` in UTC (roughly the same as GMT), not `08:50`. `+01:00` means that the time comes from a place where the clocks are 1 hour ahead of UTC, so to get the UTC time 1 hour should be subtracted, not added.

```
    DateTimeFormatter desiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String date = "2018-12-08T07:50:00+01:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeInUtc = dateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    date = dateTimeInUtc.format(desiredFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2018-12-08 06:50:00

Using your other example, `2018-12-08T07:50:00+04:00`, the output is

> 2018-12-08 03:50:00

I am taking advantage of the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format. `OffsetDateTime` parses this format as its default, that is, we don’t need to specify the format in a `DateTimeFormatter` (as we do for your desired result format).

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

`2018-12-08T07:50:00+01:00`, the `+01:00` in the end does not mean `adding hh:mm`, it means the datetime is already local date time, in GMT it is `2018-12-08T06:50:00`.

You can use `string.replaceAll` to remove `T` and `+01:00`:

```
String input = "2018-12-08T07:50:00+01:00";
input = input.replaceAll("T", " ");
input = input.replaceAll("\\+.*", "");
System.out.println(input);  // 2018-12-08 07:50:00
```

or parse and re-format it:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-08T07:50:00+01:00");
String time = offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).replace("T", " ");
System.out.println(time); // 2018-12-08 07:50:00
```

Comment: I clearly prefer parsing and reformatting over the low-level string operation using regular expressions. Also one should want to store the date-time in a variable of type `OffsetDateTime` anyway.

Comment: @OleV.V. If the result is just for UI, then these two approaches does not make difference. Otherwise the second one is preffered.