# How to convert 2017-08-01T16:00:00-04:00 to timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing

I am looking to convert the date from default Date format to timestamp in Java.
I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
String string = "2017-08-01T16:00:00-04:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-mm:ss");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
System.out.println(date);
```

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
>   '2017-08-01T16:00:00-04:00' could not be parsed at index 20
>
> at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>     at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)

Comment: You're missing a zone, and have minutes and seconds twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `LocalDate` for a `String` that

1. contains information about the time of day, wich would have required a `LocalDateTime` and
2. contains an offset, wich cannot be considered by a `LocalDateTime`.

Instead, use an `OffsetDateTime`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "2017-08-01T16:00:00-04:00";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(string);
    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
}
```

Output:

```
2017-08-01T16:00:00-04:00
```

In addition, your pattern in `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-mm:ss");` has serious flaws, like duplicate items.

You can of course print the result using a pattern different from the input (which complies with the ISO 8601 standard):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "2017-08-01T16:00:00-04:00";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(string);
    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")));
}
```

Output this time:

```
01.08.2017 16:00:00 -0400
```

Comment: I suggest printing in a format other than the input

Comment: @cricket_007 neat suggestion, thanks... Added a second example.

Comment: @deHaar thanks for help. Could you also specify how to convert `OffsetDateTime` to timestamp correctly?

Comment: @StanislavFedosov do you mean a `java.sql.Timestamp`? Or some representation like milliseconds?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651210/convert-offsetdatetime-to-utc-timestamp)...

Comment: An `OffsetDateTIme` *is* a timestamp in the sense that it represents a well-defined moment in time. If you had something else in mind when you said timestamp, please specify. We can probably provide what you want when we understand what.